# Отображение скрытых в .gitignore файлов

Tags: git, github, gitignore

В форкнутом проекте в `.gitignore` прописаны неотслеживаемые файлы (в частности, с настройками) путем указания `cms/media`.

Можно ли вернуться к коммиту, в котором были добавлены эти изменения в файл `.gitignore`, исправить его и с помощью `filter-branch`, переписать историю коммитов, чтобы в общем итоге файл отобразился?

---

добавлено из комментария:

Что нужно сделать, если мне нужно изменить, например, `setting.json`, но он не подтягивается `git pull`-ом с гитхаба? потому что я полагала, что это из-за того, что `setting.json` указан в `.gitignore`, или то, что не подтягивается, означает, что `setting.json` в репозитории и не находится?

Comment: а конечная цель какова? вы хотите добавить какие-то файлы, упомянутые в `.gitignore`, в репозиторий? так добавляйте: `git add путь/к/файлу/каталогу`. для этого переписывать историю совсем не обязательно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет,конечная цель - это подтянуть файл, который был указан в .gitignore и поэтому не подтягивается git pull'ом с github'a

Comment: содерижимое файла `.gitignore` **никак** не влияет на содержимое репозитория и на рабочую копию файлов, извлечённых из репозитория. а в репозитории у вас находится то же самое, что и на github-е: **объекты** типа commit, tree и blob. но не файлы и не каталоги, которые вы наблюдаете в рабочей копии вашего репозитория.

Comment: А что вам мешает удалить эту строчку из .gitignore и создать руками файлы из истории?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, тогда не могли бы Вы подсказать, что нужно сделать,если мне нужно изменить, например, setting.json, но он не подтягивается git pull'ом с гитхаба? потому что я полагала,что это из-за того,что setting.json указан в .gitignore , или то,что не подтягивается, означает,что setting.json в репозитории и не находится? Заранее спасибо

Comment: @korytoff, в этом и заключался вопрос. как восстановить файлы из истории, потому что создать руками не предоставляется возможным из-за отсутствия сведений об их содержимом и оформлении

Comment: @onlNas ```git checkout ХЕШ_КОММИТА_ГДЕ_ЕСТЬ_НУЖНЫЕ_ФАЙЛЫ```

Comment: @korytoff, Cпасибо. Не подскажите еще,как можно изменить файл и переписать всю историю уже с данными измененного файла?

Comment: зачем историю то переписывать? Создайте новый коммит с восстановленным файлом как написал @alexanderbarakin

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> он не подтягивается git pull'ом с гитхаба

командой `pull` вообще не «подтягивается» никаких файлов. `pull` — это две последовательно выполняемые команды: `fetch` и `checkout`.

`fetch` копирует новые **объекты** (типа *commit*, *tree*, *blob*) из указанного репозитория (например, с сервера `github.com`) в ваш локальный репозиторий. истины ради — при этом получается ещё некоторая мета-информация типа «куда указывает та или иная ветка» (ветка в *git* — это плавающий указатель на commit).

`checkout` распаковывает (при необходимости) объекты из репозитория и воссоздаёт дерево файлов/каталогов — рабочую копию вашего репозитория.

если после такой распаковки в рабочей копии нет файла, то, значит, он не упоминается в объекте типа tree, на который ссылается объект типа commit, для которого и выполнялась команда `checkout`.

---

если вы уверены, что некий файл когда-то в репозитории присутствовал, вы можете проверить это с помощью команды:

```
$ git log -- путь/к/файлу
```

будут выведены все коммиты, которыми этот файл изменялся. если ничего не будет выведено, значит, этот файл в репозитории никогда не присутствовал (по крайней мере с таким именем — `путь/к/файлу`).

если коммиты отобразились, вы можете получить содержимое данного файла после любого из этих коммитов (но не самого последнего по времени — ведь этим коммитом файл был удалён или переименован) с помощью:

```
$ git checkout хэш-коммита -- путь/к/файлу
```

получив содержимое (или создав его «с нуля») и отредактировав при необходимости, вы уже можете добавить этот файл в индекс (опция `-f` необходима для игнорирования содержимого `.gitignore`):

```
$ git add -f путь/к/файлу
```

и закрепить этот факт коммитом. и никакое содержимое `.gitignore` вам не помешает этого сделать.

---

и переписывать историю коммитов по такому ничтожному поводу вовсе нет необходимости.

Comment: Разве не надо писать `git add --force путь/к/файлу`, чтобы добавить файл, скрытый гитигнором?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, Спасибо! а как можно просмотреть список файлов,который был после определенного коммита?

Comment: @onlNas, http://stackoverflow.com/a/444317/4827341 : `git ls-tree --name-only -r хэш-коммита`